# How can I put something just outside of a minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

That is to say, I am looking to have the copyright sign align with the last `o` in `Foo`. Below is my code so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{100mm}
\begin{flushright}
\resizebox{30mm}{!}{Foo}\\ %\textcopyright should go here!
Bar
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like a 1-time thing, I just applied some negative kern and a `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{100mm}
\begin{flushright}
\resizebox{30mm}{!}{Foo}\\ %\textcopyright should go here!
Bar
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}%
\kern-2pt\raisebox{6.9pt}{\copyright}

\end{document}
```

[image]